# Access AWS Amplify DataStore via a NodeJS application running on a raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I built this mobile application using AWS Amplify, which store data into its DataStore model. I wish to access the DataStore on the raspberry pi running a NodeJS app. I tried using amplify by passing the tokens via bluetooth, which authenticate successfully, but only query/save locally.

Alternative is to manually build lambdas via API gateway to interact with the DynamoTables directly, but this would require the lambda to know about the generated table from amplify.

Is there a simpler way to get Amplify working directly on a non-cloud NodeJS app? Any other alternatives?